Canvas не реагирует на мышь в Unity после перехода на hdrp
в кратце, у меня был проект на билд-ин, я создал новый на hdrp и перенес туда все канвасы и скрипты для них, что были в прошлом проекте, но заметил что при открытии любого из 10 разных канвасов (открываються они на кнопку) у меня не нажимаються кнопки, просто как будто я их не нажимаю, так же у меня была система DragAndDrop для перетаскивания предметов и их выбрасивания, а когда я их хочу перетащить, то абсолютно ничего не реагирует на мышь, мб нужно оптимизировать код под hdrp или добавить какую то настройку? Я просто новичок в юнити и вот решил начать разбираться в hdrp

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Проверь есть ли у тебя в сцене EventSystem, возможно при переносе упустил

Если был апгрейд версии Unity, то, возможно, по умолчанию в новом проекте используется новая система инпута, тогда нужно или включить в нем старую, или перейти на новую.
